# How to call a stored procedure in another procedure and use the result of it in the same procedure of Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to use the inout return in my procedure like this:

```
do $$ 
declare
film_count text;
begin
-- get the number of films
 CALL abc('999-M-120-20200906-E726265', 
 '911120006710', '120', null);
  film_count = o_ricode;
   -- display a message
   raise notice 'The number of films is %', film_count;
end $$;
```

where `o_ricode` is inout param of proc 'abc'.

ERROR:  `procedure parameter "o_ricode" is an output parameter but the corresponding argument is not writable CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at CALL SQL state: 42601`

Calling `abc` procedure separately giving the expected results but calls in another procedure not working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abc(
INOUT o_ricode text)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
 AS $BODY$
DECLARE

BEGIN
 o_ricode := 'SUCCESS';
END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid SQL.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe updated the code...please have a look

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name help me to get the film_count value  posted in above count

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is clean - you can use only variables on positions of `INOUT` arguments. Procedure is not a function, and the function is not the procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc(INOUT arg1 text)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'arg1 = %', arg1;
  arg1 := 'xxxx';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DO $$
DECLARE var text;
BEGIN
   -- CALL proc('AHOJ'); -- this is your issue
   var := 'AHOJ';
   -- procedure invocation and passing value by ref
   -- in this context, the procedure has not result,
   -- but it can have side effects (outer variables
   -- used as INOUT arguments can be changed)
   CALL proc(var);
   RAISE NOTICE 'var = %', var;
END;
$$;

NOTICE:  arg1 = AHOJ
NOTICE:  var = xxxx
DO
```

Procedures and functions (in Postgres) has different mechanism of passing `INOUT` variables. For procedures Postgres emulates passing value by reference (it is only emulation). Passing values (and taking result) is significantly different for functions.

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(INOUT arg1 text)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'arg1 = %', arg1;
  arg1 := 'xxxx';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DO $$
DECLARE var text;
BEGIN
   -- function execution, argument is passed as value,
   -- and the variable has assigned the result of function
   var := func('AHOJ');
   RAISE NOTICE 'var = %', var;
END;
$$;

NOTICE:  arg1 = AHOJ
NOTICE:  var = xxxx
DO
```